# Warning message related to NSFileManager

Tags: iphone

```
NSString *newPath = [[theFileName stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] movePath:myString1 toPath:newPath handler:nil];
```

warning message?: **NSFileManager may not respond to '-movePath:toPath:handdler'**

what is that?

Answer (score 0):

movePath: is a deprecated function as of Mac OSX 10.5+

Which version of iOS/MacOSX are you targeting?

Also, Apple suggest to use `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [`moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/moveItemAtPath%3atoPath%3aerror%3a).

```
NSError * error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPathInFull toPath:newPathInFull error:&error];
if ( error ) {
    /* Error renaming the file. */
}
```

You can look at [`this tutorial`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/moveItemAtPath%3atoPath%3aerror%3a) too.

Comment: how to rename file (use NSFileManager )?

Comment: @Ganesh If you are looking to rename, use the method mentioned in the answer and ensure you are providing the full path for both the arguments.

Comment: @Ganesh But that will depend on the old path being correct. It looks like `theFileName` might be correct path but I can only guess with the little information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` not `movePath:toPath:handler:`.

The `movePath:toPath:handler:` is not available on iOS.

Look at [NSFileManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for iOS.